# How to correct this loop using an array

Tags: python

If any keyword from an array is mentioned in the title, don't click the title. If the title doesn't mention any of the keywords click the title.

Right now it clicks all the time, and I know why but I don't know how to fix it. It always clicks because it goes through the whole array and eventually there is a keyword that is not in the title. Ideas?

```
arr = ["bunny", "watch", "book"]

title = ("The book of coding. (e-book) by Seb Tota").lower()
length = len(arr)
for i in range(0,length - 1):
    if arr[i] in title:
        print "dont click"
    else:
        print "click"
```

This should not click the title because arr[2] is in the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want it to print or not print for the entire array, you can use `any` with a comprehension:

```
if any(word in title for word in arr):
    print("dont click")
else:
    print("click")
```

In fact the code almost reads like your description of the problem:

> If any keyword from an array is mentioned in the title

Comment: Both your and Bazingaa code got it working, this is much simples though.

Answer (score 0):

Using index variables when you don't need them is unpythonic. There's no need for `range` here. (By the way, the stop argument is the first number you *don't* want, just like a list slice.)

```
arr = ["bunny", "watch", "book"]

title = ("The book of coding. (e-book) by Seb Tota").lower()
for s in arr:
    if s in title:
        print "dont click"
        break
else:
    print "click"
```

Python allows an else clause in for loops for when you're searching for the first answer, but still need a default when you don't break the loop. But this find-first pattern is something you can actually do in one line.

```
print next(("dont click" for s in arr if s in title), "click")
```

Comment: This will still print click twice and dont click once. The OP wants only dont click if either word is present

Comment: @Bazingaa the indentation is correct. Loops can have an else clause in Python. Try running it yourself.

Comment: I just realized that your and my code will print dont click even if we replace the word book by boo or by bo or by just b. That's what  `in` does. The OP wants to see if the words are existing as a whole. But I assume the OP will not have incomplete words